# MySQL Joining to Same Table with Multiple ON Conditions?

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements

Still a mysql newb and I looked extensively through previous questions trying to find an appropriate solution.

I have two tables `CaseReportsTempImport2011Q3` and `FDADrugsDB`, I want to do a left join to match `CaseReportsTempImport2011Q3.drugname` to `FDADrugsDB.ReferenceDrugName` and `FDADrugsDB.DrugName`

What I envisioned was something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CaseReportsTempImport2011Q3.DRUGNAME)
, FDADrugsDB_Product.drugname
, FDADrugsDB_Product.ReferenceDrug
, FDADrugsDB_Product.activeingred
FROM CaseReportsTempImport2011Q3
LEFT JOIN FDADrugsDB_Product ON CaseReportsTempImport2011Q3.DRUGNAME LIKE TRIM(FDADrugsDB_Product.ReferenceDrug) 
LEFT JOIN FDADrugsDB_Product ON CaseReportsTempImport2011Q3.DRUGNAME LIKE TRIM(FDADrugsDB_Product.DrugName) 
ORDER BY LENGTH(CaseReportsTempImport2011Q3.DRUGNAME) ASC
```

But that doesn't work I get 'Not unique table/alias: 'FDADrugsDB_Product'' - Any help?

Thanks

**EDIT FOR BETTER SOLUTION REQUEST/REPHRASE**
Per borealids "However, I'm not sure this is what you want to do - joining the table twice will produce a multiplicative number of results. I think you might have wanted one join with an ON ... OR ..., making the join condition an "or" of the two reasons for linkage."

I would like to know how to do that.

**SOLUTION**
ON CaseReportsTempImport2011Q3.DRUGNAME LIKE TRIM(FDADrugsDB_Product.ReferenceDrug) OR CaseReportsTempImport2011Q3.DRUGNAME LIKE TRIM(FDADrugsDB_Product.DrugName

Thanks tom and borealid.

Comment: Just use `AND` / `OR` as you would with `WHERE` like `JOIN foo ON foo.fk = bar.id AND foo.name = bar.name` and remove the second `JOIN` or alias your tables though that seems pointless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the query you wrote valid, you need to assign two different relation names to the two uses of the same table.

```
LEFT JOIN FDADrugsDB_Product FDA_first ON
```

and

```
LEFT JOIN FDADrugsDB_Product FDA_second ON
```

and then use the names `FDA_first` and `FDA_second` to refer to results from each set distinctly. Otherwise the query engine can't tell what you mean when you say `FDADrugsDB_Product` - there are two of them, each different!

However, I'm not sure this is what you want to do - joining the table twice will produce a multiplicative number of results. I think you might have wanted one join with an `ON ... OR ...`, making the join condition an "or" of the two reasons for linkage.

Comment: Yes, I would love to figure out how to do an ON OR for one join, I tried but my syntax is quite new and rusty. How would I do this?

Comment: @cerd: `ON CaseReportsTempImport2011Q3.DRUGNAME LIKE TRIM(FDADrugsDB_Product.ReferenceDrug) OR CaseReportsTempImport2011Q3.DRUGNAME LIKE TRIM(FDADrugsDB_Product.DrugName)`. That's not the same as doing two joins.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the tables alias names, otherwise MySql won't know which instance of the FDADrugsDB table you are talking about.  i.e.

```
FROM CaseReportsTempImport2011Q3 a
LEFT JOIN FDADrugsDB_Product b ON CaseReportsTempImport2011Q3.DRUGNAME LIKE    TRIM(FDADrugsDB_Product.ReferenceDrug) 
LEFT JOIN FDADrugsDB_Product c  ON CaseReportsTempImport2011Q3.DRUGNAME LIKE TRIM(FDADrugsDB_Product.DrugName)
```

Comment: You forgot to use the alias names in the `LIKE`.

Comment: thanks.  I was just giving a quick example and not checking the whole syntax.  bad practice on my part as it would lead to confusion :-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not nitpicking, just worried they would try running your query and get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
  ...
FROM
  CaseReportsTempImport2011Q3  i
  LEFT JOIN FDADrugsDB_Product p ON    i.DRUGNAME LIKE TRIM(p.ReferenceDrug) 
                                    OR i.DRUGNAME LIKE TRIM(p.DrugName) 
ORDER BY 
  LENGTH(i.DRUGNAME) ASC
```

Note that you should probably use `=` instead of `LIKE`, unless `ReferenceDrug` and `DrugName` contain match patterns.

Comment: Yeah the data is pretty dirty so have to use a LIKE and maybe even some REGEXP.

Comment: @cerd Yeah, but without including a `%` somewhere in your condition, `LIKE` behaves like `=`. Anyway, if that's what you need, it's okay.